# How do I plot a fourth order system with bodegraph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, bodegraph

I wanted to plot a fourth order system with bodegraph:

G(s) = s^2/((s+3)^4)

But I dont get how to set the transfer function with bodegraph.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bodegraph}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}
\renewcommand{\UnitedB}{\def\Unitx{rad/s}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=20/4,yscale=4/30]
\begin{scope}[yscale=4/6]
\semilog{-1}{1}{-50}{-10}
\BodeGraph{-1:1}{20*log10(abs(10**t**2/sqrt(10**t*+3)**4))}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[yshift=-50cm,yscale=4/25]
\OrdBode{30}
\semilog{-1}{1}{-180}{0}
\BodeGraph{-1:1}{20*log10(abs(10**t**2/sqrt(10**t*+3)**4))}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please link to that package `bodegraph` and explain a bit, what you were expecting to see and what you do see and what you have tried to fix it. Right now, everybody who does not know what a bodegraph is, will have to do some research first in order to help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you use bodegraph, you have to use Bodegraph's specific commands to plot the functions.
Bodegraph can only trace elementary functions (first order, second order, integrator)
in your case, it is enough to remember that your 4th order function is built in a logarithmic diagram like the sum of four first order and two derivations (in log integrations with a negative sign).

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
%\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bodegraph}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}
\renewcommand{\UnitedB}{\def\Unitx{rad/s}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=20/5]
\begin{scope}[yscale=4/60]
\semilog{-1}{2}{-100}{-10}
\BodeGraph{-1:2}{
-2*\IntAmp{1}
+4*\POAmp{0.3333}{0.3333}
}
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[yshift=-12cm,yscale=1/45]
\OrdBode{30}
\semilog{-1}{2}{-180}{180}
\BodeGraph{-1:2}{
-2*\IntArg{1}
+4*\POArg{0.3333}{0.3333}
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]